# Setting the scroll position of a textview on segment change

Tags: ios

I am having a segment bar which is having 5 segments. Each segment is used to display separate text in the text view. The problem comes when I scroll the text view and leave the scroller somewhere in between and Then I switch to the other segment the scroller position does not change and it shows the text from the middle only. What I want is that witch each segment vale changed the scroller position of my textview should reach to the top.

I have tried several inbuilt method but none of them seems to work.
If you need the code for this problem then let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use below code every segment controller

```
   [textview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:YES];
```

Comment: no it is not having any effect on the scroll position of the textview. can u suggest something else